# Orbeon Forms: Passing Data between Global/Application Library and the Form

Tags: orbeon

We are currently using the ***Global*** and ***Application Libraries*** in our forms.

However we cannot work out how to reference data between the two libraries.

So the lower form has data in SECTION-A (global library) and we want to pull some of that data into SECTION-3 (application library).

We have tried using the following xPath format in a controls Initial Value box:

- //Field_Name_In_SECTION_A
- xxf:instance('|fr-form-instance|')//Field_Name_In_SECTION_A

But neither appear to work.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

PeteA

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It was a publishing issue..

The following option does work:

- xxf:instance('|fr-form-instance|')//Field_Name_In_SECTION_A